# No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: jpa, spring-transactions, spring-test

I am new to the jpa and spring world and I am currently doing some unit test on a simple method but keep getting this error message only when I run my test class in unit test mode:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:223)
at $Proxy19.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at com.gemstone.integration.PersonDao.getPersonByUserNamePassword(PersonDao.java:59)
at com.gemstone.integration.PersonDaoTest.getPersonByUserNamePassword_Exist(PersonDaoTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

However the code works fine when i run my project it retrieves the data correctly(Not in unit test mode).

Please find below my method which the unit test will be based on:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean getPersonByUserNamePassword(String firsName, String password) {

    String hql = "from Person p where p.firstName = :firsName and p.password =:password";
    Session mysession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Query query = mysession.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("firsName", firsName);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    List<Person> results = query.list();

    if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

My unit test below:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/Intcontext.xml" })

public class PersonDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    PersonDao personDao;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void getPersonByUserNamePassword_Exist() {

        String firsName = "Andy";
        String password = "123";

        boolean isUserExists = personDao.getPersonByUserNamePassword(firsName,
                password);

        Assert.assertTrue(isUserExists);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why i am getting No transactional EntityManager available error please?:(

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `@TestExecutionListeners`? Also, show how you configure JPA, transaction manager, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
```

you have completely (albeit unintentionally) *disabled* support for test-managed transactions. The reason is that you have omitted `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` from the list of declared listeners.

Note, however, that `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` is declared transparently by default. Thus, when you delete your `@TestExecutionListeners` declaration from your test class, `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` is once again enabled.

You can of course find details [in the Spring Reference Manual here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework ;) )

Answer (score 2):

I think EntityManager is null.Try Like this,may be it work

```
private EntityManager entityManager = null;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Thnks for the response, as stated earlier by @axtavt  removing TestExecutionListeners resolved my problem. But i don't know why though.:( could you please tell us why  the annotation TestExecutionListeners triggered the error stated earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem when I try the unit tests with IntelliJ, even though its working using `cli` of `maven-surefire-plugin`

it turns out that IntelliJ build was using javac compiler and even though it specified in pox.xml to use ajc compiler there is a reported bug for IntelliJ at [IDEA-135483](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135483)

that made `@Transactional` not working 
and give you `No transactional EntityManager available`

if that is your case, you need to change java compiler to use `ajc` instead of `javac` and `post-compile weave mode` in project structure